# Adding paginator without using exampledatabase in cdk-table

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, angular2-components

I am trying to add paginator in cdk-table. It works fine without paginator. I am getting my data to display from a master component through input property.

```
export class BankStatementDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() detail: any;
  displayedColumns = ['amount', 'balanceAfterTranc', 'category', 'date', 'description', 'remark', 'type', 'valueDate'];

  dataSource: TrancDatSource | null;

  @ViewChild(MdPaginator) paginator: MdPaginator;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.detail) {
      this.dataSource = new TrancDatSource(this.detail.transactions, this.paginator);
      console.log('Data Source: ', this.dataSource);
    }
  }

export interface TransactionDetail {
  amount: string;
  balanceAfterTranc: string;
  category: string;
  date: string;
  description: string;
  remark: string;
  type: string;
  valueDate: string;
}

export class TrancDatSource extends DataSource<TransactionDetail> {
  constructor(
    private tranc: TransactionDetail[],
    private _paginator: MdPaginator,
  ) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<TransactionDetail[]> {
    return Observable.merge(this.tranc, this._paginator.page).map(() => {
      const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
      return this.tranc.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
    });
    // return Observable.of(this.tranc);
  }
  disconnect() { }
}
```

When i console log Data Source in ngOnChange(), i am getting paginator undefined. Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it necessary to use BehaviorSubject in order to add pagination? If remove pagination and return Observable.of(this.tranc) instead of return Observable.merge(.....) then i works fine.